# How to get reference to the element that causes ElementClickInterceptedException?

Tags: .net, selenium-webdriver

I have no knowledge nor control over how the UI is generated in the page that I need to test. There are multiple loader indicators and I can't differentiate them nor see them, but Selenium is faster so it clicks them. All of them have class `LoaderSpinner` and no id,

I can wait until all of them disappear, but that causes big performance issues, I want to wait until the element that caused an `ElementClickInterceptedException` disappears.

**Question** How can I get reference to the element that caused `ElementClickInterceptedException`?

Answer (score 0):

You already have a reference to it... it's the element you just tried to click that caused the exception.

This is what I use. It handles `ElementClickInterceptedException` and `StaleElementReferenceException` by just trying again until the timeout is reached. You just have to pass in the locator and a timeout if you don't like the default 10s and it takes care of the rest.

```
public void Click(By locator, int timeOut = 10)
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    while (DateTime.Now < now.AddSeconds(timeOut))
    {
        try
        {
            new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeOut)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(locator)).Click();

            return;
        }
        catch (ElementClickInterceptedException)
        {
            // do nothing, loop again
        }
        catch (StaleElementReferenceException)
        {
            // do nothing, loop again
        }
    }

    throw new Exception($"Not able to click element <{locator}> within {timeOut}s.");
}
```